# How can I catch RelayObervable Unhandled error when graphql errors are returned?

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern

My backend is returning the following response:

```
const errorMessage = {
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'User is logged out',
    },
  ],
  data: null,
};
return res.status(200).json(errorMessage);
```

My react-native app using relay is returning the following error:

```
RelayObservable: Unhandled Error Error: 
Relay request for `HomeQuery` failed by the following reasons:
```

This error shows up when I try to query the backend and it returns the above 'errorMessage' graphql errors array. I have no way of catching this error in my relay network layer BEFORE it throws the redscreen. My Relay Environment looks like this:

```
const network = new RelayNetworkLayer([
  urlMiddleware({
    url: () => Promise.resolve(`${config.endpoint}backend`),
    headers: async () => authenticateHeaders(fetchHeaders),
  }),
  retryMiddleware({ fetchTimeout: 1000 }),
  next => req => {
    if (!req.uploadbles) {
      req.Accept = 'application/json';
      req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    }

    return next(req);
  },
  next => async req => {
    const res = await next(req);
    if (isLoggedOut(res)) {
      // Using react-navigation, route to the login screen
      dispatch(routeToLogin())
      // I also tried returning `dispatch(routeToLogin())` and `{ data: null, errors: res.payload.errors }` without luck
    }

    return res;
  }
  ]);
```

Is there a way I can navigate using `dispatch(routeToLogin())` without seeing the redscreen error when graphql errors are returned?

#### Edit 1

For `react-relay-network-modern`: You can add the noThrow option like so: `new RelayNetworkLayer(middlewares, { noThrow: true });`

The noThrow option doesn't exist for `react-relay-network-layer` (relay classic), is there anything I can do to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try `noThrow` option:

```
const network = new RelayNetworkLayer(middlewares, { noThrow: true });
```

Comment: Are you sure that `noThrow` is available on the react-relay-network-layer package? I added it, and the errors still occur. I also tried searching for 'noThrow' in the code and it doesn't exist. Remember that this isn't the `modern` package, it's the classic one.

Comment: I confirmed that this fixes the issue for react-relay-network-modern ✅However, the react-relay-network-layer` package still throws the error.